# how to send metrics to influx oss2 using jolokia in telegraf config?

Tags: telegraf, influxdb-2, jolokia, telegraf-inputs-plugin

after running teltelegraf -debug with jolokia config

```
[[inputs.jolokia2_agent]]
  urls = ["http://<other ip>:8080/jolokia-war-unsecured-1.6.2/"]

   [[inputs.jolokia2_agent.metric]]
     name  = "jr"
     mbean = "java.lang:type=Runtime"
     paths = ["Uptime"]
```

I get this errors:

```
[agent] Initializing plugins
2022-07-02T12:51:57Z D! [agent] Connecting outputs
2022-07-02T12:51:57Z D! [agent] Attempting connection to [outputs.influxdb_v2]
2022-07-02T12:51:57Z D! [agent] Successfully connected to outputs.influxdb_v2
2022-07-02T12:51:57Z D! [agent] Starting service inputs
2022-07-02T12:52:07Z E! [outputs.influxdb_v2] When writing to [https://MYIP:8086]: Post "https://MYIP:8086/api/v2/write?bucket=monitoringdb&org=myorg": http: server gave HTTP response to HTTPS client
2022-07-02T12:52:07Z D! [outputs.influxdb_v2] Buffer fullness: 81 / 10000 metrics
2022-07-02T12:52:07Z E! [agent] Error writing to outputs.influxdb_v2: failed to send metrics to any configured server(s)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 2022-07-02T12:52:07Z E! [outputs.influxdb_v2] When writing to [https://MYIP:8086]: Post "https://MYIP:8086/api/v2/write?bucket=monitoringdb&org=myorg": http: server gave HTTP response to HTTPS client

This error is coming from your influxdb output. It says your client is using `https`; however, the server responded with an `http` response. In your config, you probably specified a URL with `https://`, but the server is probably only using `http://`.